# Nopcommerce MegaMenu - Add custom menu to link towards products

Tags: razor, nopcommerce, megamenu

I was wondering if there were any Nopcommerce veterans out here that could help me adjust my newly hosted Nopcommerce website.

I have a client that has a handful of products. I would like them
displayed (without images) in the Sevenspikes Mega Menu. They are
however very different products and I would like them displayed as
such for example:

> Our Products > Gifts > Food , > Gifts > Postcards , > Gifts > Liquor
>
> Our Products > Photography > Weddings , \ > Photography > Family
>   shoots , \ > Photography > Parties
>
> Our Products > Personalisation > Labels , \ > Personalisation >
>   Clothing, \ > Personalisation > Graphic Design

Every one of those final links is to refer to a single product or a SE on the website. Is this possible within CSHTML and what code should I add and where?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done without any code modification.

Step 01.

Create categories for your 3 examples in admin.

Eg: Under "Our Products" crate "Gifts". under Gifts create "Post Cards". Likewise.

```
Our Products > Gifts > Food , > Gifts > Postcards , > Gifts > Liquor

Our Products > Photography > Weddings , \ > Photography > Family shoots , \ > Photography > Parties

Our Products > Personalisation > Labels , \ > Personalisation > Clothing, \ > Personalisation > Graphic Design
```

Step 02.

Create your product in admin. Then go to category map of created product and map above 3 categories.

Done.